# Is set of empty set is a subset of empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is {∅} ⊆ ∅ true?

I don't think so, because If ∅ is a subset of every set (also  ∅)  ∅ ⊆ A it means that no elements are a part of any set, but in this case {∅} ⊆ ∅ must be true if every element in A is an element in B, B is just an empty set that not contains elements.

Am I right? 
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true.

> "I don't think so..."

So the outcome of your thinking on this is correct. Unfortunately I have troubles in following the thinking itself expressed in your question, and the fact that it is quite a story makes me suspicuous.

More concise you can say: $\{\varnothing\}$ has an element, and if $\{\varnothing\}\subseteq\varnothing$ is true then this element will also be an element of $\varnothing$.

This however is absurd, since by definition $\varnothing$ has no elements. We conclude that $\{\varnothing\}\subseteq\varnothing$ is false.

Comment: Excellent explanation, now I understand. thank you

Comment: You are very welcome.